# Angular 7.1.4 - What causes routerLink to fully reload the next page?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

This is a strange issue that I am not able to debug and doesn't produce any error in the logs. I have a page setup with `mat-tab-nav-bar` with 3 buttons on the toolbar using `routerLink=""` to connect to different pages.

The toolbar component template looks something like this.

```js
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar class="bottom-toolbar">

  <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/articles" routerLinkActive="active">
    Articles 
  </a>

  <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/categories" routerLinkActive="active">
    Categories
  </a>

  <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/settings" routerLinkActive="active">
    Settings
  </a>

</nav>
```

This toolbar component is called in `app.component.html` along with a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

FYI, the routes for `/articles`, `/categories` and `/settings` are all calling separate feature modules and none of them are lazy loaded. The `/articles` route has a `canActivate` guard while the `/categories` and `/settings` routes don't (I disabled them for testing purposes).

Now to the problem. The app loads fine going through user authentication and all that stuff and lands at the Articles page normally.

In the Articles page, when the user clicks on Categories, Angular does a full page reload to load the Categories page. When the user clicks back, the app goes back to Articles page without a full page reload. When the user clicks back on the Categories link, this time the Categories page routing is working as expected. So it only breaks on first attempt.

Same behavior for the Settings page.

If I disabled the `canActivate` guard for all 3 routes, all routings work as expected.

So what is causing the `routerLink` to fully reload the route on first click?

Comment: Can you show a bit of your route guard implementation?

Comment: This reloading happened to me couple of times. The problem was really odd. It started appearing after I added *ngIf to one part of the nav-bar component.

Comment: I didn't manage to solve this issue properly because of tight deadline. So I resorted to a hacky workaround that quickly redirects the Articles page to Settings page and then back to Articles page on first load within milliseconds.